# OCaml elements in List1 but not in List2

Tags: ocaml

I have the code:

```
let rec subtract list1 list2 =  
  match list2 with   
  | [] -> list1  
  | h::t -> List.filter (fun x -> List.mem x list1) list2
```

Instead of outputting the elements that occur in both lists, I want the elements that *are* in list1 but *not* in list2. Basically a kind of reversed version of `List.mem`.

For example, if I input lists of `[1;2;3;4]` and `[1;2;3]`, `[4]` should be the output.

Answer (score 2):

Your current code returns a filtered version of list2, which can't be right. You want to return a filtered version of list1, surely. So your call should look something more like this:

```
List.filter (fun x -> blah blah) list1
```

It's also worth noting that, given the functions you're calling, you don't really need to break list2 down into its parts (with a match). The functions are already able to look inside it.

It's not at all hard to logically reverse a function, i.e., to calculate the inverse boolean result. The `not` operator does this.

(Obviously I'm trying not to just write the code for you.)